# Updates to the FAQ for sister sites

Tags: discussion

I was browsing some other FAQ's for Stack Exchange sites, and noticed a nice "sister site" example at Stack Overflow. I was thinking we could emulate something like this to point to *our* sister sites such as AVP, Graphic Design, etc. This is what Stack Overflow has in their [FAQ](https://serverfault.com/faq):

```
We also have sister sites that cover specific topics in more detail:

 - Stack Overflow for Programming Super User for general 
 - Networking, Hardware, and Technology Unix & Linux for general Unix... 
 - DBA for Advanced Database topics 
 - IT Security for Advanced Security (implementation, theory, white hat)
```

Comment: If this gets any attention and upvotes, when do we decide to add it or not to the FAQ? If it gets over X number of upvotes to an answer below?

Comment: Democracy?  Just do it!

Answer (score 5):

We also have [sister sites](http://stackexchange.com/sites/) that cover specific topics in more detail:

- [Audio-Video Production](https://video.stackexchange.com/) for audio, video, and media creation.
- [Graphic Design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/) for graphic arts, web design, layout and printing, and Illustration.
- [Super User](https://superuser.com/) for computer hardware and computer software.

Comment: Definitely think these three would be useful for reducing the number of questions closed as off-topic or at least giving us something consistent to refer directly to when closing a question.

Comment: @jrista - Can you do this? I don't think non-mods can edit the FAQ.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see this until now. I'll update now.

Comment: FAQ has been updated!